# Difficulty with initially training Neural Networks

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, octave, gradient-descent

I am researching artificial neural networks (ANN). I am trying to train many different ANN's with main emphasis of research being correlation between structure change and prediction rate.

I have noticed it is quite common for the training algorithms to converge in the first 100 or so iterations to near initial state due to training step being too small. I have no clear idea why this would happen. Has anyone confronted with the same problem? What could be the reason for this? Is there a better way to overcome the problem than just force the iteration schemes to work their way through beginning where the problem seems to lie?

I have been training my networks in Octave using fmincg and fminunc. Backprop. to get the gradient and cost function is the same as logistic regressions. The problem occurred for network structure of 10 neurons in first and 10 neurons in second hidden layer. MNIST Database is being used for both training and test sets.

Addition: 
Fminunc seems not to do very well at all on three layered ANN, but under some random variables with two layered ANN seems to converge without a problem. Conjugate gradient seems to work if forced through initial phase.

Could the problem be the random initialization of weights? Could having too low of a variability [-0.12; 0;12] causing the problem?

Edit: Made network structure part little more clear.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you mean by training step? I thought you meant the learning rate, but then you mentioned using fmincg and fminunc, which do not use a learning rate. Also, what do you mean by "a better way to overcome the problem [what problem exactly? are the results bad? how bad?] than just force the iteration schemes [force how, you have no control over what fmincg and fminunc do?] to work their way through beginning where the problem seems to lie [I do not understand this]". Also what does "10 - 10 hidden layers" mean?

Comment: Are you referring to the vanishing gradient problem? It can happen if you have too many hidden layers. Have you tried using Rectified Linear Units?

Comment: Training step being one iteration of scheme. The problem is that I have to manually force (meaning setting tolerance to 0) e.g first 100 iterations to run with tolerance of 1e-7 (this is very small compared to the real tolerance I am after: e.g e-4 is sufficient) being already met. The results are the same as if I had done no training at all. 10 - 10 hidden layers means a network structure: Input layer size - hidden layer size 1 - hidden layer size 2 - output layer size. With hidden layer sizes being 10.

Comment: Sounds like a vanishing gradient I think. Does it work better with a single hidden layer?

Comment: I am fairly confident, that vanishing gradient is not the reason with two hidden layer network. There simply aren't enough layers of back propagation. Also the problem is in the beginning of the training, where there should be sufficient gradient magnitude from the first layer. For single layers everything worked fine. But also these aren't the interesting structures to look at. Also I might not had enough of them to manifest the problem. I only had 50 in comparison I have 500 two layer ANNs and 5000 three layer ANNs to train.

Comment: If you are getting slow training progress at the start of training this would suggest (to me at least) that you could increase it with either a larger learning rate, or an increased level of random initialization.